# In PHP Composer, configure dependencies to install the latest version of the package which is still compatible with the current platform or framework

Tags: php, composer-php

Imagine there is some framework X and modules A and B developed for this framework. Also, A depends on B (any version of B allowed). Originally, A v.10 and B v1.0 were developed for X v1.0.

B and A are released new versions periodically. This will lead to when I update A, B would also get updated. Let's assume a few years passed and now in our repository there is A of v3.0 and B of v6.0 (and both A and B are still for X v1.0).

Now we have some local installation which have remained in the original state (X, A and B are all of v1.0). So if I updated A at this point, this would end up in updating A to v3.0 and B to v6.0. But let's assume I didn't run this update before X v2.0 release.

Now framework X v2.0 gets released and it's not compatible with X v1.0. Vendor of B then released B v7.0 for X v2.0. Vendor of A, however, hasn't updated it for X v2.0 yet. The attempt to update A to v3.0 will lead to an attempt to update B to v7.0 which won't work and the upgrade procedure will be terminated.

What I wanted would be that updating A to 3.0 will lead to updating B to v6.0 as it was the last compatible version for X v1.0.

If in A there was dependency "B 1.x", this would protect me from getting issues when B v2.0 for X v2.0 comes out. However, I won't be able to get updates to B when it gets new major releases which can still be compatible with X v1.0. This means the module vendor cannot make v2.0 if it still runs on X v1.0 framework, all updates to B must be v1.x.

So I'd better have freedom to set versions to modules (incl. major versions) independently of X framework versions. I need mechanism to resolve dependencies in the way that the most recent version of dependency gets installed ONLY if it's compatible with the current environment. If it's not compatible, the most recent compatible version will be selected instead of stopping the whole process.

It is possible to "tell" Composer "Update to the latest versions which are possible under the current conditions" instead simply of "Update to the latest versions"?

Comment: It's possible to update to the latest version of a package but not under the condition of said package "playing nice" with another X package that you have installed. Unfortunately you'll have to figure that one out on your own and keep up with the release notes of the packages you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all need to understand versioning semantic. In few words:

version: `X.Y.Z`

where:

- X: major version (breaking changes)
- Y: minor version (features
  adding, must be compatible with previous versions in the same major
  version)
- Z: bug fixes (must be compatible with previous versions in
  the same major version)

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

So if you write:

for example: `^1.2.3`

it will update library to the latest including new feature (e.g: `1.*.*`) (but it will keep the same major version, e.g if available it will update to `1.4.5`)

`~1.2.3` is more strict and it will update only bug fixes version (e.g: `1.2.*`)

but, unfortunately not all libraries follow version semantic, so  anyway you have to check update result.

But in both cases minimal required version is: `1.2.3`

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to find the latest compatible version... I have to go to packagist and click through each version to check their parent package version (like sub/package v#.#.# to parent/package targeted version range)... it's a pain in the [bleep]. I'm not seeing how to run a composer command that just does this for me.

Comment: just run:

`composer require package/name`

composer will try to install latest compatible version

Comment: At Alex (I don't know why the at symbol and your username is being deleted when I submit this comment): I've tried `composer require` for packages (without specifying version numbers) on two big old repos recently, and gotten slews of errors about version conflicts, mostly in the lock file. It's super-annoying trying to upgrade these old bloated repos. Hunt and peck, trial and error, rabbit holes, red herrings, wild goose chases... it's become dependency hell when composer is supposed to make this relatively easy. I don't know the good solutions here.

Comment: What error do you have? If you have something like, package X requires version y but it's locked on version z - you can try to remove composer.lock and run composer install, before run that you need to include right version of required package.

Comment: At alex-kapustin: the slew of errors won't fit here  Part of the problem is I don't know which versions of everything to require... I thought composer was supposed to figure that out automatically (highest compatible version I'd think). I mean, removing the lock file gets rid of the "locked at" errors, but it's been difficult trying to figure out what the right versions or version ranges to require/install.